# New column based on row values - A better way?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

There's surely a better way to create a column that matches the 'target' column?

I scoured Stack for an answer, but it appears nobody has needed to know how to do this. Maybe from a completely stupid perspective (my head may have been in Stata mode as that's how my boss thinks, who asked me to create this new 'output' variable).

```
A       <-c("bears",  "bears",     "na",   "pandas",     "pandas",    "bears",   "pandas")
B       <-c("bears",  "pandas",     "na",   "bears",     "na",          "bears",   "pandas")
target  <-c("bears", "the_zoo",   "na",   "the_zoo",  "pandas",   "bears",   "pandas")
df_test <-data.frame(A,B,target,  stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

class(df_test$B)
for(i in 1:nrow(df_test)){
                          # Case: 1: Both are equal
    df_test$output[i] <- ifelse(df_test$A[i] == df_test$B[i],
                               yes = as.character(df_test$A[i]), 
                               # Case 2: A contains NA
                                no = ifelse(df_test$A[i] == "na",
                                            yes = as.character(df_test$B[i]),
                                            # Case 2.2: B contains NA
                                            no = ifelse(df_test$B[i] =="na",
                                                        yes = as.character(df_test$A[i]),
                                                        # Case 3: All other possibilities are "the_zoo"
                                                        no = "the_zoo"
                                                        )))
                                                    }
df_test



> df_test
       A      B  target  output
1  bears  bears   bears   bears
2  bears pandas the_zoo the_zoo
3     na     na      na      na
4 pandas  bears the_zoo the_zoo
5 pandas     na  pandas  pandas
6  bears  bears   bears   bears
7 pandas pandas  pandas  pandas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with

```
A       <-c("bears",  "bears",     "na",   "pandas",     "pandas",    "bears",   "pandas")
B       <-c("bears",  "pandas",     "na",   "bears",     "na",          "bears",   "pandas")
target  <-c("bears", "the_zoo",   "na",   "the_zoo",  "pandas",   "bears",   "pandas")
df_test <-data.frame(A,B,target,  stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

df_test$test <- with(df_test, ifelse(A == B, A, 
                       ifelse(A == "na",B, 
                              ifelse(B == "na", A, "the_zoo"))))


print(df_test)
```

Which produces:

```
       A      B  target    test
1  bears  bears   bears   bears
2  bears pandas the_zoo the_zoo
3     na     na      na      na
4 pandas  bears the_zoo the_zoo
5 pandas     na  pandas  pandas
6  bears  bears   bears   bears
7 pandas pandas  pandas  pandas
```

You dont need the for loop as the ifelse is already vectorized.

Comment: Your code not work correctly because his NA's are character, look your 5ª row.

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz just changed it

Comment: I really think I tried this, but obviously I made a mistake somewhere. But presumably you need the $ operator before the As and Bs?

Comment: @SeánMcK sorry about that. I added the a with, which you can wrap around and then you dont need the $

Answer (score 0):

One option here to clean up your code would be to use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df_test$output <-
case_when(
    df_test$A == df_test$B ~ as.character(df_test$A),
    df_test$A == "na" ~ as.character(df_test$B),
    df_test$B =="na" ~ as.character(df_test$A),
    TRUE ~ "the_zoo"
)
```

Note that if the `A` and `B` columns are already character type, as part of your code seems to assume, then you may remove the unnecessary calls to `as.character` above.

Comment: Love the dplyr solution too- I really should have thought about this one. In general do you have any thoughts about when case_when should be used Vs ifelse?

Comment: @SeánMcK It's really a matter of code readability and maintainability.  The code in the answer you accepted is hard to read, and relatively hard to maintain.  From a performance point of view, I think either of the answers is fine.